# Background-size doesn't work

Tags: css, background

Here's my CSS:

```
.banner-text-BG {
    background: #00A7E1 url(images/sale_tag.png) left center no-repeat !important;  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px 10px 10px 70px;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px 10px 10px 70px;
    border-radius: 70px 10px 10px 70px;     
    padding-left: 70px;
}
```

Contrary to all the other styles, the "background-size: 20px;" has no effect on my page, is not visible in Firebug, and as a sidenote is not highlighted as a valid CSS instruction in Notepad++. Same with "background-size: 20px;" or "background-size: 20px auto;"

Am I missing something? Why does it not work?

Comment: Have you tried removing everything from the first background line except the actual image? Maybe something is conflicting there?

Comment: Let's get the basics out of the way. What browser/version are you using?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As the [background-size docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) state:

> If the value of this property is not set in a background shorthand
>   property that is applied to the element after the background-size CSS
>   property, the value of this property is then reset to its initial
>   value by the shorthand property.

In other words, if you're using the shorthand property but don't include the background-size rule as a part of it, the separate background-size is essentially reset and ignored.

So to get around that you just need to roll it into the background shorthand you're already using by adding a slash after the background-position and including your size:

```
background: #00A7E1 url(http://placekitten.com/200/200) left center/20px 20px no-repeat !important;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n3qEX/)**

Comment: That seems annoying. Why would they purposely do that?

Comment: Yeah that's stupid. Thanks for the tip, solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 3):

"!important" should be avoided.

I would split all background attributes as such:

```css
.banner-text-BG {
    background-image: url(images/sale_tag.png) 
    background-position: left center;
    background-color: #00A7E1; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;   
}
```

Comment: better to use this one if you handling image from inline and rest code from class, but for the performance I would avoid to use this code

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `!important` in the background shorthand is preventing the `background-size` property from applying, at least in Chrome.

Removing the `!important` allows the background-sizing to take effect. See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QVXsj/9/